# Recaptcha has empty iframe with identical HTML

Tags: php, html, http, iframe, recaptcha

I am using a recaptcha for users without JS enabled.

```
$recaptcha=new recaptcha();
$recaptcha=$recaptcha->recaptcha_get_html('6LexxxxxxxxL_p4P5V2xxxxxxxuWX4');
$echo($recaptcha);
```

But, as you can see, the iframe is empty.

[image]

So, I cut and paste the HTML and put it in another file, and now it works with identical HTML!

[image]

I happen to be using Twig to display it (with `|raw`), however I have created a miny Twig template, and don't witness this, so I don't believe it has anything to do with Twig.

The page is created using PHP.  The HTML has to be okay as it works when I copy it to another file.  Could it be some strange header?  What could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The page which didn't work was using HTTPS.

To make it work with HTTPS, use:

```
$recaptcha=$recaptcha->recaptcha_get_html(RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC,null,true);
```